# Query vs. C# method to retrieve database metadata

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, metadata, getschema

I need  to retrieve for each table in the database the following info:

1. All columns names
2. For each column its type
3. Type max length

The possible way to do that is to run a query (even can execute it using await, i.e. async):

```
select object_NAME(c.object_id), c.name, t.name, c.max_length
from sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.types t
    ON t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
```

On the other hand there is GetSchema method on connection which makes the same:

```
DataTable columns = connection.GetSchema(SqlClientMetaDataCollectionNames.Columns, restrictions);
foreach (DataRow row in columns.Rows)
{
    string columnName = row[3].ToString();
    string columnDataType = row[7].ToString();   
    string columnDataTypeLen = row[8].ToString();
}
```

Which of the methods is better to use? Looks that second one should be faster - am I right?
What about performance?

Comment: the first one is better because it uses database only to get the information where as the second one has a for loop also. generally speaking getting data in database level is better than calculating in application

Comment: If you have no SQL code or don't own the database, go with C#. Do you want to maintain this stored procedure in the future? I would not.

Comment: What do you call it in a loop? Call once, for the first row. Do you expect the metadata to change depending on row? It won't.

Comment: @abatishchev OK I will probably remove the loop.Can you elaborate a little more your first comment.You say that the C# is better because I don't have to deal with stored procedure?

Comment: How do you plan to call the query? Using SqlConnection/SqlCommand? It won't be efficient as a stored procedure could be. But then you need to maintain it over the time. And anyway you'll need to support further version of SQL Server and possible changes. With C# code it will be much easier. Until performance is really critical for you.

Comment: Just to make it clear.The reason that using query from perfomance point of view is better its because C# compiler essentially translate it TSQL?

Comment: If you are concerned about performance then you should read this http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000117.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either method and cache the result

Meta data doesn't change under normal operation so performance is a non-issue

Comment: How to chache the results?

Comment: Any case for the first time what are pros. and cons. : if I use async query execution vs. GetSchema?

Comment: Use c# cache, or save into variable with scope suitable for your requirements. What have you tried?

Comment: @Yakov Both have do do same amount of work. Performance different is not going to be noticeable. Performance is the least of your worries here. Learn how to cache well

Comment: Either way you are querying the database. All that method can do is to call a SQL command (query or SP) to retrieve the data (about the schema metadata) from the DB. It ill not be very different from your select.