# Retrieve Column name in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I was looking around on SO on how to retrieve the column name and I tried out some solutions but when I use this method, for example, I recieve these column names and not my actual column namnes (ID, Status, Title etc.):

- TABLE_CATALOG
- TABLE_SCHEMA
- TABLE_NAME
- TABLE_TYPE

  ```
   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
        {

          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
          builder.ConnectionString = this.ConnectionString;
          string server = builder.DataSource;
          string database = builder.InitialCatalog;

          connection.Open();
          DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
          Tables = new List<Table>();
          foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
          {
              /* Add Table */
              Table t = new Table();
              string tableName = row[2].ToString();
              t.Name = tableName;

              /* Add columns */
              //DataTable dtCols = connection.GetSchema("Columns", new[] { "StarTrackerDB", null, "dbo.Tickets" });
              t.Columns = new List<Column>();

              foreach (DataColumn column in row.Table.Columns)
              {
                  Column c = new Column();
                  c.Name = column.ColumnName;
                  t.Columns.Add(c);
              }

              Tables.Add(t);
          }
      }
  ```

**EDIT:**

I want to retrieve it in C# i.e. not execute an SQL query string in my code.

**EDIT2**

Current output:

- TABLE_CATALOG
- TABLE_SCHEMA
- TABLE_NAME
- TABLE_TYPE

Expected output:

- ID
- Status
- Title

etc. the column names in the tables. the `string tableName` is set correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: How do you return the column names from a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600446/sql-server-how-do-you-return-the-column-names-from-a-table)

Comment: Posting the output (actual & desired) would help a lot

Comment: It's stated in the description but here it goes again: "I recieve these column names and not my actual column namnes (ID, Status, Title etc.): [Output]" I will try to rephrase it if it was hard to understand.

Comment: You're looking for metadata. Maybe this will get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053829/query-vs-c-sharp-method-to-retrieve-database-metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited your code and was able to get the tables and columns with the code below.

```
   public void testeStackOverflow()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
        {

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.ConnectionString = this.ConnectionString;
            string server = builder.DataSource;
            string database = builder.InitialCatalog;

            connection.Open();


            DataTable schemaTables = connection.GetSchema("Tables");

            foreach (System.Data.DataRow rowTable in schemaTables.Rows)
            {
                String TableName = rowTable.ItemArray[2].ToString();

                string[] restrictionsColumns = new string[4];
                restrictionsColumns[2] = TableName;
                DataTable schemaColumns = connection.GetSchema("Columns", restrictionsColumns);

                foreach (System.Data.DataRow rowColumn in schemaColumns.Rows)
                {
                    string ColumnName = rowColumn[3].ToString();
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much dear sir, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Get schema information of all the columns in current database

```
DataTable allColumnsSchemaTable = connection.GetSchema("Columns");
```

You can specify the Catalog, Schema, Table Name, Column Name to get the specified column(s).
You can use four restrictions for Column, so you should create a 4 members array.
For the array, 0-member represents Catalog; 1-member represents Schema; 2-member represents Table Name; 3-member represents Column Name.

e.g. get columns for table MyTable:

```
String[] columnRestrictions = new String[4];
columnRestrictions[2] = "MyTable";
DataTable myTableSchemaTable = connection.GetSchema("Columns", columnRestrictions);
```

To get the data from these tables:

```
var columnDetails = from info in table.AsEnumerable()
                         select new {
                            TableCatalog = info["TABLE_CATALOG"],
                            TableSchema = info["TABLE_SCHEMA"],
                            TableName = info["TABLE_NAME"],
                            ColumnName = info["COLUMN_NAME"],
                            DataType = info["DATA_TYPE"]
                         };
```

Get schema information of all the IndexColumns in current database

```
DataTable allIndexColumnsSchemaTable = connection.GetSchema("IndexColumns");
```

You can specify the Catalog, Schema, Table Name, Constraint Name, Column Name to get the specified column(s).
You can use five restrictions for Column, so you should create a 5 members array.
For the array, 0-member represents Catalog; 1-member represents Schema; 2-member represents Table Name; 3-member represents Constraint Name; 4-member represents Column Name.

```
String[] indexColumnsRestrictions = new String[5];
indexColumnsRestrictions[2] = "Course";
indexColumnsRestrictions[4] = "CourseID";
DataTable courseIdIndexSchemaTable = connection.GetSchema("IndexColumns", indexColumnsRestrictions);
```

To get the data from these tables:

```
var columnDetails = from info in indexColumnsTable.AsEnumerable()
                     select new {
                        TableSchema = info["table_schema"],
                        TableName = info["table_name"],
                        ColumnName = info["column_name"],
                        ConstraintSchema = info["constraint_schema"],
                        ConstraintName = info["constraint_name"],
                        KeyType = info["KeyType"]
                     };
```